# How can I duplicate and translate an existing object many times?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding in blender and am trying to create a simple for loop that makes a grid of objects. I've accomplished this before with the primitive cube, but I want to replace the cubes with a lego obj I've made separately.

Code for the for loop:

```
import bpy

import random

spacing = 2.2

for x in range (10):

    for y in range (10):

        location = (x * spacing, y * spacing, random.random() * 2)

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=location, scale=(1, 1, 1))"
```

This code simply lets me translate the lego object but not add a new lego object to the scene for every run, which is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['lego']

obj.location.z += 1
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! So you want to duplicate an object that is already present in your file and apply some translation to it ?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I want to be able to use my Lego obj in the same way we use the primitive cube to make a grid using a for loop.

Comment: Alright then Chris' answer below should satisfy you :)

Comment: I took the liberty to change your question title so it reflects (imho) more clearly your goal. Feel free to edit back if you don't like it

Comment: That’s perfect, thank you again ! c:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['lego'].copy()
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

obj.location.z += 1
```

if you use

```
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['lego']
```

then obj is the lego object itself. Or in programming languages we say "it references the lego object". So if you change the location afterwards, it changes the location of lego object.

So first you have to make a copy of the object.

```
bpy.context.scene.objects['lego'].copy()
```

then you can reference it to a new obj variable:

```
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['lego'].copy()
```

and then the new object has to be linked to the scene, so that Blender adds it to your scene:

```
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: You helped me immensely!

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer helped me, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.